# How do I avoid using index while mapping a multidimensional array in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state that holds two arrays, both the same length:

```
    const [ data, setData ] = useState<{ headers: string[], values: (string | number)[] }>({ headers: [], values: [] });
```

And I am trying to do something like this:

```
<Row className={'d-flex flex-row py-3'}>
    {data && data.headers.map((header, index) => (
        <Col className="displayInput d-flex flex-column align-items-start m-2">
            <label className="ml-2 bold">{header}</label>
            <p className="ml-2">{data.values[index]}</p>
        </Col>
    ))}
</Row>
```

where I can list each of the header and value items through mapping. I know this is the wrong way to do it and the indexing does not work, but I am struggling to find a solution to this?

Comment: I think you're doing it right, the best way would be to have 1 array instead of 2

Comment: Since its an array, without index how can you identify this array1[0] is equal to array2[0], i think it will be easy if you have an array of objects where one property will be reference for each array so we can pick that object based on the same value. Otherwise index is the only way

Answer (score 0):

So there a 2 main ways to do this:

1. Using the index is technically not wrong, as long as they are mapped perfectly:

```
<Row className={'d-flex flex-row py-3'}>
    {data && data.headers.map((header, index) => (
        <Col key={header} className="displayInput d-flex flex-column align-items-start m-2"> // Note the key
            <label className="ml-2 bold">{header}</label>
            <p className="ml-2">{data.values[index]}</p>
        </Col>
    ))}
</Row>
```

2. Using a merged object:

```
    const [ data, setData ] = useState<{header: string; value: string | number;}[]>([]);
```

```
<Row className={'d-flex flex-row py-3'}>
    {data && data.headers.map(({header, value}) => (
        <Col key={header} className="displayInput d-flex flex-column align-items-start m-2"> // Note the key
            <label className="ml-2 bold">{header}</label>
            <p className="ml-2">{value}</p>
        </Col>
    ))}
</Row>
```